# Architecture for site with subdomains per city

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an application which has subdomains for  a number of different cities. For simplicity's sake, you can think of it like craigslist. It's also important to note that there is an `admin.mysite.com` that needs to generate reports with data from all of the other sites.

I'm having some trouble deciding on a best practice for how to lay things out.

Here are some things I'm considering:

1. How should I lay out the database(s)? I'm leaning toward creating a db for each site, and then an admin db with views that pull from the other databases for reports.
2. How should I keep track of which city/subdomain a user is in? As of now, I'm using an action filter to set a Session variable for the city, which I don't like. I'm thinking maybe create a base controller that has something like a `currentCity` variable that I'd set via a filter instead of session state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's truly a single application, with the content being determined by the host header name, then making multiple databases will become a maintenance nightmare sooner or later.  A single database will do just fine.

As for your second question you'll have to determine if a user id can be used in more than one city and your answer will come from that.  If you are driving this by subdomains, then I fail to see the need for a session variable that duplicates what's in the host header (Request["SERVER_NAME"])

Answer (score 1):

You are describing it yourself actually.

I would go with the following domain model:

```
public class City {
   id,
   name,
   // other info

   Site site;

}
```

Then you have your site model:

```
public class Site{
   id,
   // back navigation : City 
   Then site properties.
}
```

Ps. i would go with a single database as well.

You can manage your users as City/site users as follows:

```
class User{
  // props
  City navigation
  Site navigation
}
```